# Require in functions without require()

Tags: php, pdo

Any idea to require files in top of php file and require will be also in functions without require in functions?

Comment: What? I have literally no idea what you are talking about. Can you show an example?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: I require() connecting to my database in php file, but I do not have require() in function, so my array from another file is not loaded. Is that any solution how to make require() for all functions (it means public, for all) and don't require in every functions?

Comment: Pass the array into the functions, or use a static class, or global var (not recommended).

Comment: I have reason for having array in another file. Static class sounds good. Can you send my some close information? I absolutely don't have idea how do it.